# При отправке email получаю ошибку

Tags: html, apache, сервер

```
Not Found

The requested URL /brif/ was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) Server at eranewgames.ru Port 80
```

В чем прблема?

Comment: каким образом производится «отправка email»? укажите это, пожалуйста, прямо в вопросе.

Comment: видимо после отправки стоит редирект на /brif/, но этой страницы либо нет, либо указан неверный путь до нее

Comment: А может на хостинге нет такой возможности как отправк почты? как узнать?